# How do I do this recursion in golang

Tags: go, recursion

I have the below go code and I am trying to do a recursion. However, the go compiler is complaining of a cyclic reference. **Of course** I have a cyclic reference; it's a recursion.

I have tried moving the recursion into the main function and out. Same issue. How can I achieve this recursion? The error line is: `return lookup(deref.Interface()) // recursion error 'cyclic definition'`

```
christianb@christianb-mac terraform-provider% go build
# github.com/terraform-provider/pkg/foo/repositories.go:773:5: initialization loop:
        /Users/christianb/dev/terraform-provider/pkg/foo/repositories.go:773:5: lookup refers to
        /Users/christianb/dev/terraform-provider/pkg/foo/repositories.go:774:18: glob..func6.1 refers to
        /Users/christianb/dev/terraform-provider/pkg/foo/artifactory/repositories.go:773:5: lookup
```

```golang
type AutoMapper func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{}

var lookup = func() func(payload interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    var handlePtr = func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
        deref := reflect.Indirect(thing)
        if deref.CanAddr() {
            if deref.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                return lookup(deref.Interface()) // recursion error 'cyclic definition'
            }
            return map[string]interface{}{
                field.Tag.Get("hcl"): deref.Interface(),
            }
        }
        return map[string]interface{}{}
    }
    var checkForHcl = func(mapper AutoMapper) AutoMapper {
        return func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
            if field.Tag.Get("hcl") != "" {
                return mapper(field, thing)
            }
            return map[string]interface{}{}
        }
    }
    lk := map[reflect.Kind]AutoMapper{}

    find := func(payload interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
        values := map[string]interface{}{}
        var t = reflect.TypeOf(payload)
        var v = reflect.ValueOf(payload)
        if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            t = t.Elem()
            v = v.Elem()
        }
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            field := t.Field(i)
            thing := v.Field(i)
            for key, value := range lk[thing.Kind()](field, thing) {
                values[key] = value
            }

        }
        return values
    }
    lk[reflect.Struct] = checkForHcl(func(f reflect.StructField, t reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
        return find(t.Interface())
    })
    lk[reflect.Slice] = checkForHcl(func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
        return map[string]interface{}{
            field.Tag.Get("hcl"): thing.Interface().([]string),
        }
    })
    lk[reflect.Ptr] = checkForHcl(handlePtr)
    return find
}()
```

Comment: As everyone explained, the problem isn't recursion, it's syntax.  A variable can't be referenced before it's defined, but Go compiler is smart enough to handle self referential functions with the `func <Name>(...) ... {... }` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function cannot reference itself by name, because it is an *anonymous function*. It only becomes named once it gets assigned to the variable `lookup`. Lexically, this only happens once the value being assigned is fully parsed. This is different from a normal `func` declaration, where the name is available immediately (which makes recursion rather cleaner):

```golang
func myFunc(arg) result {
    // ... do something ...
    // now we can call the function recursively
    return myFunc(arg)
}
```

In your case, a regular `func` declaration won't work, so you need some kind of "forward declaration" to make the name available, which requires a small amount of duplication:

```golang
// forward declare the function
var myFunc func(arg) result

myFunc = func(arg) result {
    // ... do something ...
    // now we can call the function recursively
    return myFunc(arg)
}
```

To do the same thing in a global context, see [Burak's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69804830/11424673)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an initialization loop, not recursion. You are referring to a variable from that variable's definition. You can do:

```
var lookup func() func(payload interface{}) map[string]interface{}

func init() {
   lookup=func() func(payload interface{}) map[string]interface{} {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did as other suggested in various permutations and got the same issue. Ultimately, this is what I got to work

```golang
type AutoMapper func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{}

func checkForHcl(mapper AutoMapper) AutoMapper {
    return func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
        if field.Tag.Get("hcl") != "" {
            return mapper(field, thing)
        }
        return map[string]interface{}{}
    }
}

func findInspector(kind reflect.Kind) AutoMapper {
    switch kind {
    case reflect.Struct:
        return checkForHcl(func(f reflect.StructField, t reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
            return lookup(t.Interface())
        })
    case reflect.Ptr:
        return checkForHcl(func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
            deref := reflect.Indirect(thing)
            if deref.CanAddr() {
                if deref.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                    return lookup(deref.Interface())
                }
                return map[string]interface{}{
                    field.Tag.Get("hcl"): deref.Interface(),
                }
            }
            return map[string]interface{}{}
        })
    case reflect.Slice:
        return checkForHcl(func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
            return map[string]interface{}{
                field.Tag.Get("hcl"): castToInterfaceArr(thing.Interface().([]string)),
            }
        })
    }
    return checkForHcl(func(field reflect.StructField, thing reflect.Value) map[string]interface{} {
        return map[string]interface{}{
            field.Tag.Get("hcl"): thing.Interface(),
        }
    })
}

func lookup(payload interface{}) map[string]interface{} {

    values := map[string]interface{}{}
    var t = reflect.TypeOf(payload)
    var v = reflect.ValueOf(payload)
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        thing := v.Field(i)
        typeInspector := findInspector(thing.Kind())
        for key, value := range typeInspector(field, thing) {
            values[key] = value
        }
    }
    return values
}
```